# C# Reorder Directory.GetFiles result from the list of another object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sorting

I'd like to get files from a specific folder in order to display them in a carousel, so I'm using :

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("path/to/my/folder")
```

However, the files are ordered by their name in `files[]`

In my page (a strongly-typed view), my `Model` contains a dozen of properties, including a `List<FileModel> filesToDisplay` which is populated by pictures to display. A `FileModel` is a custom model, which contains the name, the size, a boolean `IsMain` and other some pictures properties.

On the other hand, the `filesToDisplay` list is populated from my database, in which I'm going to search which pictures I have to display. All the pictures are in the same directory, but I can't always display ALL the pictures of this directory ; this is why I'm searching to the DB which ones to display.

My goal is to display files in my carousel :

- With the picture where `IsMain` is true in first position. There is *always* one and only one picture where `IsMain` is true
- Then, as a second picture, the first picture where `IsMain` is false **from `filesToDisplay`**
- Then as a third picute, the seconde picture where `IsMain` is false **from `filesToDisplay`**

etc...
Of course, the order in `filesToDisplay` can be (and is almost always) different from `files[]`

So, I'd like to do something like this :

```
files.OrderBy(filesToDisplay.IsMain).ThenBy(filesToDisplay(x => !x.IsMain))
```

which is of course impossible.

How can I express it in "correct" C# ?
Thanks for your help !

(Yes, I've already seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227757/sort-one-list-based-on-another), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676707/sorting-a-list-based-on-the-contents-of-another-list?rq=1) which are very close to mine, but I was unable to adapt the answer to my problem). Sorry for newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want the sorted files to be in the same order as the files to display, except that you want IsMain to be first. I think this code should satisfy that requirement;

```
       string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("path/to/my/folder");

        var sortedFiles = (from o in filesToDisplay
                              join i in files
                              on o.Name equals Path.GetFileName(i)
                              orderby o.IsMain descending 
                              select i).ToArray();
```

This will order the sorted files by `IsMain` first, of which there is always one so that goes to the first element in the array then the rest of the ordering is via the LINQ join where the `sortedFiles` sequence uses the existing order from the `filesToDisplay` sequence.

(This assumes that `FileModel` holds the `FileName` and each entry in `string[] files` is a filePath containing the file names.
eg. FileModel FileName: Picture1.jpg, files[0]: C:/RandomPath/Images/Picture1.jpg as you need a value to link up each file in `files[]` to each `FileModel` in `filesToDisplay`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ; this perfectly works after very small adaptations to fit my model.